# Setting OS X environment variables including spaces from a key/value file using the env command

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables

I'm using OS x and bash and trying to set environment variables from a file using the *env* command but I can't understand why it's not working.

Example file (dummy.env):

```
KEYA=VALUEA
KEYB=\"VALUE B\"
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
env $(cat dummy.env  | grep -v "^#" | xargs) <command>
```

Output:

> env: B: No such file or directory

However, if I do the following:

Get the output of command

```
cat dummy.env  | grep -v "^#" | xargs
```

which gives me

> KEYA=VALA KEYB="VALUE B"

Then take that exact output and substitute it in the env command such as

```
env KEYA=VALA KEYB="VALUE B" <command>
```

it works.

I know I'm probably missing something basic here but I just don't understand how in the first case it doesn't work because it seems to ignore the double quotes yet in the second case it works.

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a subshell? Like, put `export KEYA=VALUEA` in dummy.env and `(. dummy.env; <command>)`.

Comment: You can't do this with command substitution output for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Quotes inside your file will be passed to `env` as part of the literal text of the variables' values.

Comment: Also, is it a necessary part of the input that it uses `\"foo\"` instead of `"foo"`? It's extra work to undo that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for providing that link...I simply do not understand enough about what is really going on under the hood and that is a good reference. I'll read up some more. The reason I escaped the double quotes is because I thought they were being stripped by xargs and resulting in the value with spaces being interpreted incorrectly by the env command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ideally, you shouldn't use `env` for this.

Instead:

```
(set -a; . dummy.env; exec yourcommand)
```

- Because of the parens, we `fork()` off a copy of our shell for all of the below, so it doesn't change the environment of the shell that started it.
- Because of `set -a`, we export all variables subsequently set in that subshell to the environment.
- Because of the `exec`, we consume the subshell and replace it with the copy of `yourcommand`.

---

#### But if you really, *really* wanted to for some reason...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

env_args=( )
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  [[ $key = "#"* ]] && continue     # skip comments
  [[ $key && $value ]] || continue  # skip lines without a key and a value
  case $value in
    '\"'*'\"')  value=${value#'\"'}; value=${value%'\"'} ;;
    '"'*'"')    value=${value#'"'}; value=${value%'"'} ;;
  esac
  env_args+=( "$key=$value" )
done <dummy.env

env "${env_args[@]}" your_command
```

- Because this content isn't going through the shell's parser, we need to strip the (literal) quotes off the content after it's been read, and the (literal) backslashes as well.
- To ensure that argument boundaries are held together and respected, we assemble an *array*, and quote carefully both on additions to that array and its final expansion.

Answer (score 3):

The version of `env` that ships with macOS has a `-S` option that, with an appropriately modified `dummy.env`, can do what you want. (It even knows how to skip `#`-comments already.)

```
$ cat dummy.env
KEYA=VALUEA
KEYB="VALUE\_B"
# KEYC=unread
$ env -i -S "$(<dummy.env)" sh -c 'echo "$KEYB"'
VALUE B
$ env -i -S "$(<dummy.env)" sh -c 'echo "$KEYA"'
VALUEA
```

`env` will parse the *string* given to the `-S` option (here, constructed from the full contents of your `dummy.env` file) in order to build the desired environment strings.

`\_` is a documented escape character that becomes a normal space when building the environment.

---

Note, though, that the only option supported by POSIX `env` is the `-i` option (which causes `env` to use only command-line arguments to build the environment, ignoring its own). Any other option your local version may support is a non-portable extension.

Comment: Heh -- this is indeed a MacOS-specific question; fair call. :)

Comment: Looks like GNU `env` also supports a `-S` option, but it has a slightly different meaning, and might not work as well in general for this use-case. (It seems to be intended for use in a shebang, not in constructing a full-blown environment from a given string.)